# How to remove duplicate ID values but keep the row with the highest age

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data.table, aggregate

I have the following dataset where I have replicates of the same ID entry (example: 20103 is repeated twice):

```
head(Data)
##   X    ID        DOB sector meters Oct  Res_FROM    Res_TO  Exp_FROM     Exp_TO
## 1 1 20100  8/24/1979    H38   6400   W 8/15/1979 5/15/1991 8/24/1979 12/31/1988
## 2 2 20101   5/5/1980    B01   1600  NW 5/15/1980 4/15/1991 5/15/1980 12/31/1988
## 3 3 20102  3/17/1979    H04   1600  SW 6/15/1972 8/15/1979 3/17/1979  8/15/1979
## 4 4 20103 11/30/1981    B09   3200  NE 1/15/1982 1/15/1984 1/15/1982  1/15/1984
## 5 5 20103 11/30/1981    B37   8000   N 1/15/1984 4/15/1986 1/15/1984  4/15/1986
## 6 6 20104   9/1/1978    B09   3200  NE 1/15/1982 1/15/1984 1/15/1982  1/15/1984
##   Exps_Grp Yr1952 Yr1953 Yr1954 Yr1955 Yr1956 Yr1957 Yr1958 Yr1959 Yr1960
## 1       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 2       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 3       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 4       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 5       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 6       NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
##   Yr1961 Yr1962 Yr1963 Yr1964 Yr1965 Yr1966 Yr1967 Yr1968 Yr1969 Yr1970 Yr1971
## 1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 2     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 4     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
## 6     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
##   Yr1972 Yr1973 Yr1974 Yr1975 Yr1976 Yr1977 Yr1978   Yr1979    Yr1980    Yr1981
## 1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 1.082616 0.7834218 0.7834218
## 2     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       NA 0.6825884 1.0937646
## 3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA 4.673775        NA        NA
## 4     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       NA        NA        NA
## 5     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       NA        NA        NA
## 6     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA       NA        NA        NA
##      Yr1982    Yr1983    Yr1984    Yr1985    Yr1986    Yr1987    Yr1988
## 1 0.7834218 0.7834218 0.7834218 0.7834218 0.7834218 0.7834218 0.1956091
## 2 1.0937646 1.0937646 1.0937646 1.0937646 1.0937646 1.0937646 0.2730972
## 3        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
## 4 2.7934596 2.8975827 0.1041230        NA        NA        NA        NA
## 5        NA        NA 0.5662659 0.5890579 0.1416258        NA        NA
## 6 2.7934596 2.8975827 0.1041230        NA        NA        NA        NA
##     Yrs_Exp arth_mean    median cumulative age
## 1 9.3616438 0.7545599 0.7834218   7.545599   9
## 2 8.6356164 0.9568931 1.0937646   8.612038   8
## 3 0.4136986 4.6737751 4.6737751   4.673775   0
## 4 2.0000000 1.9317218 2.7934596   5.795165   2
## 5 2.2493151 0.4323165 0.5662659   1.296950   4
## 6 2.0000000 1.9317218 2.7934596   5.795165   5
```

My full data has over 14,000 rows. I want to eliminate the duplicate ID entries; however, when I do this elimination, I need to keep the row that has the highest age. For example, the two rows with ID = 20103, the first age is 2 and the other age is 4. I would only want to keep the row with the highest age, which would be 4. I've used the aggregate function before, but I don't know how to apply it to only eliminate duplicates and keep the row with the highest number for age. I have included a reproducible dataset below.

```
 structure(list(X = 1:9, ID = c(20100L, 20101L, 20102L, 20103L, 
 20103L, 20104L, 20104L, 20105L, 20105L), DOB = c("8/24/1979", 
 "5/5/1980", "3/17/1979", "11/30/1981", "11/30/1981", "9/1/1978", 
 "9/1/1978", "12/3/1980", "12/3/1980"), sector = c("H38", "B01", 
 "H04", "B09", "B37", "B09", "B37", "B09", "B09"), meters = c(6400L, 
 1600L, 1600L, 3200L, 8000L, 3200L, 8000L, 3200L, 3200L), Oct = c("W", 
 "NW", "SW", "NE", "N", "NE", "N", "NE", "NE"), Res_FROM = c("8/15/1979", 
 "5/15/1980", "6/15/1972", "1/15/1982", "1/15/1984", "1/15/1982", 
 "1/15/1984", "12/15/1980", "8/15/1983"), Res_TO = c("5/15/1991", 
 "4/15/1991", "8/15/1979", "1/15/1984", "4/15/1986", "1/15/1984", 
 "4/15/1986", "8/15/1983", "3/15/1991"), Exp_FROM = c("8/24/1979", 
 "5/15/1980", "3/17/1979", "1/15/1982", "1/15/1984", "1/15/1982", 
 "1/15/1984", "12/15/1980", "8/15/1983"), Exp_TO = c("12/31/1988", 
 "12/31/1988", "8/15/1979", "1/15/1984", "4/15/1986", "1/15/1984", 
 "4/15/1986", "8/15/1983", "12/31/1988"), Exps_Grp = c(NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1952 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA, NA), Yr1953 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
     Yr1954 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1955 = c(NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1956 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1957 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA), Yr1958 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
     Yr1959 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1960 = c(NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1961 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1962 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA), Yr1963 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
     Yr1964 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1965 = c(NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1966 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1967 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA), Yr1968 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
     Yr1969 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1970 = c(NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1971 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1972 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA), Yr1973 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
     Yr1974 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1975 = c(NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1976 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Yr1977 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA), Yr1978 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
     Yr1979 = c(1.082616155, NA, 4.673775148, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA), Yr1980 = c(0.783421772, 0.682588398, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, 0.120085751, NA), Yr1981 = c(0.783421772, 1.093764595, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2.897582683, NA), Yr1982 = c(0.783421772, 
     1.093764595, NA, 2.793459642, NA, 2.793459642, NA, 2.897582683, 
     NA), Yr1983 = c(0.783421772, 1.093764595, NA, 2.897582683, 
     NA, 2.897582683, NA, 1.805844233, 1.09173845), Yr1984 = c(0.783421772, 
     1.093764595, NA, 0.104123041, 0.566265934, 0.104123041, 0.566265934, 
     NA, 2.897582683), Yr1985 = c(0.783421772, 1.093764595, NA, 
     NA, 0.589057923, NA, 0.589057923, NA, 2.897582683), Yr1986 = c(0.783421772, 
     1.093764595, NA, NA, 0.141625765, NA, 0.141625765, NA, 2.897582683
     ), Yr1987 = c(0.783421772, 1.093764595, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
     NA, 2.897582683), Yr1988 = c(0.1956091, 0.27309722, NA, NA, 
     NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.723484539), Yrs_Exp = c(9.361643836, 8.635616438, 
     0.41369863, 2, 2.249315068, 2, 2.249315068, 2.665753425, 
     5.383561644), arth_mean = c(0.754559943, 0.956893087, 4.673775148, 
     1.931721789, 0.432316541, 1.931721789, 0.432316541, 1.930273838, 
     2.234258954), median = c(0.783421772, 1.093764595, 4.673775148, 
     2.793459642, 0.566265934, 2.793459642, 0.566265934, 2.351713458, 
     2.897582683), cumulative = c(7.545599433, 8.612037782, 4.673775148, 
     5.795165366, 1.296949622, 5.795165366, 1.296949622, 7.72109535, 
     13.40555372), age = c(9L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -9L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Option using `aggregate`:

```r
aggregate(age~ID,df,function(x) max(x))
#>      ID age
#> 1 20100   9
#> 2 20101   8
#> 3 20102   0
#> 4 20103   4
#> 5 20104   7
#> 6 20105   8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: With this method, all other attributes of the table are lost.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `dplyr` way, grouping and filtering by condition has the same effect:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(ID, age) %>% # just to keep the main columns (remove this)
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(age==max(age)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
     ID   age
  <int> <int>
1 20100     9
2 20101     8
3 20102     0
4 20103     4
5 20104     7
6 20105     8
```

Comment: just to add, you may want to add a `ungroup` at the very last?

Comment: I  always ignore this. But you are right!

Comment: Oh, I was just confused to see your data output, I mean there's no metadata about grouped variable in the data ouput, but you did grouping and didn't ungrouping thereafter :) .

Answer (score 1):

Simply arrange by in decreasing order and then use `distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(ID, age) %>% 
  arrange(desc(age)) %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)

#>      ID age
#> 1 20100   9
#> 2 20101   8
#> 3 20105   8
#> 4 20104   7
#> 5 20103   4
#> 6 20102   0
```

Note that, I have only selected the two columns of interest `ID` and `age` just for concise output and to focus on the issue given here, using `select()`, which obviously you don't need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In base R

```
df_new <- df[order(df$age, decreasing = T), ]
df_new <- df_new[!duplicated(df_new$ID), ]
```

output of ID and age columns

```
> df_new[ , c("ID","age")]
     ID age
1 20100   9
2 20101   8
9 20105   8
7 20104   7
5 20103   4
3 20102   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[order(-age),.(age = first(age)),by=ID]
```

Output:

```
      ID age
1: 20100   9
2: 20101   8
3: 20105   8
4: 20104   7
5: 20103   4
6: 20102   0
```